# Is my salah valid if I don't give adhan and Iqamah?

Tags: salat, adhan

Just want to know is iqama and adhan obligatory ?

Answer (score 1):

From a fiqh perspective: neither adhan nor iqamah are necessary nor essential for the validity of the prayer.
Nevertheless scholars consider adhan having the value of a fard kifaya: so in a -Muslim- city at least one adhan should be made from a masjid, so that all Muslims in that city won't be sinning by missing to call for the prayer.

Both adhan and iqamah are sunnah and recommended acts. Even a person praying alone can perform both.
As for iqamah it is even more recommended to perform it if you pray alone. While in case you've prayed in a mosque or in a congregation an iqamah would surely be made and an adhan usually too.