# Reciting the adhan

Tags: salat, adhan

Salam, me and my mate were out playing football and we went to read Maghrib in the car park (we did a jamaat). As I was about to do the iqamah he was saying that an adhan had to be performed for the jamaat. My question is is the adhan necessary since it has already been done in a masjid so rather iqamah would be more appropriate? Jazakallah Khair.

Comment: [Is my salah valid if I don't give adhan and iqamah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62069/is-my-salah-valid-if-i-dont-give-adhan-and-iqamah) is relevant and should cover the topic already. If you want details please leave a comment. Else consider accepting that post as a duplicate

Comment: That’s fine jazakallah the answer is covered in that